# Add data to access table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have created a form in Visual studio 2010 & following is the code I am using

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        Dim dbSource = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Membership.accdb"
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()

        Dim sql = "INSERT INTO Memberdetail (Membername, Memberadd, Membercontact, Memberphone1, Memberphone2, Membersince) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Me.Memname.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Me.Memadd.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Me.Memcontact.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Me.Memphone1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Me.Memphone2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Me.DateTimePicker1.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

But this edits the only available data in the table everytime and does not add a new row to the table when I enter the new data.

Where I am wrong.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by edits?

Comment: By edit I mean that it replaces the form data with record data in the same record everytime instead of adding a new row to the table.

Comment: Have you tried running the same query in Access directly without using .net? I don't know your table structure but if membername is a primary key it won't let you add that same name twice to the table. Though it should be throwing an exception in .net if thats the case.